# IIS and RestSharp -> Response body cut off for 40x error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, restsharp

**The situation**

Seems easy enough: I have a service running on IIS 7. A client POSTS data (application/json) and I validate the data before I accept it.

If I don't accept it, I really wanted to return a 406 and the ~same~ data as body (potentially changed/corrected) [1]. Unfortunately that leads to truncated response bodies aka invalid json.

To start, lets enable passthrough for my errors, because the IIS tries to be clever otherwise:

`<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough">

    </httpErrors>`

The relevant part of my code does the moral equivalent of this:

```
HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
response.StatusDescription = StatusDescription;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
    response.ContentType = ContentType;
else
    response.ContentType = "application/json";

if (ContentEncoding != null)
    response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream))
{
    sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data));
}
```

On the client side, I'm currently doing a naive (to find the problem with the json truncation)

```
var response = myRestClient.Execute(myRestRequest);
```

**The Problem**

If the response returns a status code of 200, I get this

```
response.ContentLength == 69345
response.RawBytes.Length == 69345
```

If I change *nothing* but the returned status code (to 406 in my case), returning the *very same data*, I see this:

```
response.ContentLength == 69345
response.RawBytes.Length == 65536 // <--- Not! Good!
```

Now, 65536 is far too magic a number to be a coincident or a very reproducible result of cosmic rays. Who's *now* trying to be clever and throwing away my data if it exceeds an unsigned short in length? I'll try diving into the RestSharp codebase now, but I am really suspicious of IIS fooling with me again..

1: If this is a bad idea, please elaborate why?

Comment: Is the actual content truncated or not?

Comment: Yes, the content is truncated. But RestSharp (thanks, btw!) isn't to blame from what I can see. I really just receive that number of bytes over the wire (according to Fiddler).

Comment: Hmmmm, I have a similar issue but fiddler shows the full JSON content returned from the Tomcat server - did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: As far as i know RestSharp uses HttpWebRequest, where the default value of DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength is 65536. So i guess that's where your magic number stems from.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this post: [RestSharp RestResponse is truncating content to 64 kb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570525/restsharp-restresponse-is-truncating-content-to-64-kb/37951481#37951481)

This is happening because RestSharp uses the HttpWebRequest class from the .NET Framework. This class has a static attribute called DefaultMaximumErrorResponseLength. This attribute determines the max length of an error response, and the default value for this attribute is 64Kb.